# Rust in my Moka Coffee Pot

Tags: equipment

Hi I have a similar pot (SS Stovetop Espresso Maker) and have been using it extensively.  Recently  I have noticed a few rust spots in the section where you need to add water.  I am a coffee lover, can't imagine living without it and neither can I find a replacement for it in the area i live. Can anyone let me know if its safe to use the Moka pot after i have cleaned up the rust stains or is it advisable to discard it completely.  Please help.

Comment: There's no danger in using your pot whether it has rust stains or not, it's perfectly safe.

Comment: Make certain you clean it and dry it properly after each use.

Comment: Are you sure it's rust and not coffee stains? The ibrik (Turkish / Arabic coffee pot) at my parents house gets stained with use every now and again (it's coated and glazed on the inside so no exposed metal). I think they clean it with bleach and it removes the stains.

Comment: Thank you GdD for your assurance. Max, I normally do dry the pot after use, but I guess the last time it was used, was put away without ensuring it was totally dry, that's why the rust stains.

Comment: NRaf, it is rust stains, as the section that has the rust spots does not come in contact with the coffee powder.